# Fluent Nhibernate two queries into one

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a child query which has a parent that is in the same table. I need the child and the parent's name to build my child object. The catch is the parentID can be null because not every child has a parent:

```
var child = session.Query<Child>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == value);
        if (child.ParentId != null)
        {
            child.ParentName = session.Query<Child>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == child.ParentId).Name;
        } else
            child.ParentName = "";
 return child;
```

This looks messy to me mainly because if the parentID is null I don't want a null. Should I be concerned about this? How can I convert it to one query? Am I looking at the logic incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved this problem using two different tables. First for roots (w/o parent), second for all children - each child has reference to parent, so you are able to provide efficient queries, e.g. for the remove of root (and all children).

Comment: That is an interesting way to handle it, however; My parent objects sometimes have parents of their own due to the structure of the data.